# R: Finding the code for the data.frame method of the [ function

Tags: r, methods, generic-function, help-system

In R, how do I look at the code for the data.frame method of the [ function?

I have tried the usual plain return on [.data.frame, `[.data.frame`, and `[`.data.frame, and none of them work, nor do any of them work with getAnywhere().  getMethod("[", "data.frame") didn't work either.  <- the code designations in this paragraph actually denote being surrounded by backticks.

I'm actually looking for the standard code that lets you refer to columns by name, vector of position numbers, logical vector or negative number. If someone could  point me toward such code in a more accessible location, that would also constitute a solution from my point of view.

Comment: Try   `\`[.data.frame\` `

Comment: You were almost there. `getAnywhere(\`[.data.frame\`)`. Surrounded by backticks, the formating of comments doesn't allow them to be seen. (Yes it does, just escape them.)

Comment: or [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L551)

Comment: G5W, I would have sworn on a stack of bibles that I had tried exactly that. I guess I had a typo.

Comment: Rui Barradas, thanks, that works too.

Comment: G5W and Rui, If either of you would care to make your comment an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Ben Bolker, I went through this searching on "#". The comments, generally brief though they are, were surprisingly helpful in understanding the code. Is there a more generalized way of finding the code with comments included? I'd accept that as an answer too.